# Decomposition of a measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, singular-measures

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure on $\mathbb{R}$ corresponding to the distribution function, $F$ where

$$F(x) = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{ll} 
           0& \text{if} \,\, x<0\\
           x+1& \text{if} \,\, 0\leq x<1\\
           2x+3& \text{if} \,\, 1\leq x<2\\
           8&  \text{if} \,\, x\leq 2
\end{array} \right.
$$
Then Find the absolutely continuous part and the singular part of the measure with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know every sigma finite measure can be composite into two parts but in this question. I do not know how to begin. Please help me out.

Comment: Draw $F$ and figure out what you have to do to remove the discontinuities.

Comment: Yea,I removed the discontinuity then after what to do?

Comment: Well, then you will have a continuous function $F_c$ (that is piecewise linear, hence AC), and the difference $F_s = F-F_c$ which is the singular part.

Comment: @copper.hat : the singular part is supposed to be $G(x) = H(x) + 3H(x-1)+ H(x-2)$, a function such that $F - G$ is AC ? and the definition is $(F-G)(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$ with $f(x) = F'(x)$ where $F$ is differentiable, and $f(x) = 0$ where it is not ?

Comment: @user1952009: That is correct, with your $G$, then $F-G$ is Lipschitz and so absolutely continuous, hence differentiable ae. [$m$]. This gives $(F-G)'(x) = H(x)+H(x-1)-2H(x-2)$ whenever $x \notin \{0,1,2\}$.